# Search in listview on android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I need to do a search on the data in a list, make a filter. I bought some means of doing this in what seems to me simpler to implement Filtravel in adapting and instantiating their methods, but msm following the whole explanation here did not work. Someone seemed to help me and explain how to make this filter in my project ??? Thanks in advance!

### Adapter

```
public class AdapterBDLocal extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
private Context mContext;
private CustomFilter filter;
private List<ProdutosPesquisa> produtosList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<ProdutosPesquisa> filterList = new ArrayList<>();


public AdapterBDLocal(Context mContext, List<ProdutosPesquisa> produtosList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.produtosList = produtosList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return produtosList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return produtosList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View listItem = view;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_lista_pesquisa,viewGroup,false);

    final ProdutosPesquisa p = produtosList.get(i);

    TextView nome = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome_produto2);
    nome.setText(p.getNome_completo());

    TextView categoria = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_categoria2);
    categoria.setText(p.getCategoria());

    TextView unidade = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_unidade2);
    unidade.setText(p.getUnidade());

    Button btn_add = (Button)listItem.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    Button btn_rem = (Button)listItem.findViewById(R.id.btn_rem);


    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String m = p.getCodigo_barras();
            if(list.size()<=9){
                list.add(m);
                txt.setText(list.toString());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Adiconado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(txt.getText()!= null){

                }

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sua Lista esta grande demais!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    btn_rem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String m = p.getCodigo_barras();
            list.remove(m);
            txt.setText(list.toString());
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Removido da lista!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return listItem;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(filter == null)
    {
        filter=new CustomFilter();
    }

    return filter;
}

//INNER CLASS
class CustomFilter extends Filter
{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();

        if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0)
        {
            //CONSTARINT TO UPPER
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<ProdutosPesquisa> filters=new ArrayList<ProdutosPesquisa>();

            //get specific items
            for(int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)
            {
                if(filterList.get(i).getNome_completo().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    ProdutosPesquisa p = new ProdutosPesquisa();
                    p.setNome_completo(filterList.get(i).getNome_completo());
                    filters.add(p);
                }
            }

            results.count=filters.size();
            results.values=filters;

        }else
        {
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;

        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        produtosList = (ArrayList<ProdutosPesquisa>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 }

}
```

### Activity

```
public class PesquisaTesteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView txt;
List<ProdutosPesquisa> lista_produtos;
ListView lv;
AdapterBDLocal adapter;
public static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
private SearchView searchView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pesquisa_teste);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv2);

    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    lista_produtos = DataBaseClass.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAllProdutos();

    txt = findViewById(R.id.textView);


    adapter = new AdapterBDLocal(PesquisaTesteActivity.this,  lista_produtos);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


 }

}
```

Comment: Try in your adapter constructer, add this: this.filterList.addAll(produtosList); Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my adapter class, very simple to use just modify it according to your needs:

```
public class DriverListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables \\
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<DriverList> driverLists = null;
    private ArrayList<DriverList> arrayListDriverLists = null;
    AppCompatActivity act;

    public DriverListAdapter(Context context,
                             List<DriverList> driverLists) {
        mContext = context;
        this.driverLists = driverLists;
        arrayListDriverLists = new ArrayList<>(driverLists);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        act = (AppCompatActivity) context;

    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView driverNameTv, carNameTv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return driverLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DriverList getItem(int position) {
        return driverLists.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_items_driver_list, null);

            holder.driverNameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_items_drivers_name_tv);

            holder.carNameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_items_drivers_car_tv);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.driverNameTv.setText(driverLists.get(position).getDriverName());
        holder.carNameTv.setText(driverLists.get(position).getDriverCar());

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Filter Class for item searching
     *
     * @param charText Text to be searched
     */
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        driverLists.clear();

        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            driverLists.addAll(arrayListDriverLists);
        } else {
            for (DriverList driverList : arrayListDriverLists) {
                if (driverList.getDriverName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()) // driverList.getDriverName() will let the user to search driver's name
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    driverLists.add(driverList);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Here is my pojo class:

```
public class DriverList {

    String driverName, driverEmailId, driverCar, timestamp;


    public String getDriverName() {
        return driverName;
    }

    public void setDriverName(String driverName) {
        this.driverName = driverName;
    }

    public String getDriverEmailId() {
        return driverEmailId;
    }

    public void setDriverEmailId(String driverEmailId) {
        this.driverEmailId = driverEmailId;
    }

    public String getDriverCar() {
        return driverCar;
    }

    public void setDriverCar(String driverCar) {
        this.driverCar = driverCar;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Here is activity code for the editText where you will perform search:

```
final EditText driverSearchEt = dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_select_car_search_et);
        driverSearchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (driverSearchEt.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    if (carsListAdapter != null) {
                        carsListAdapter.filter("");
                    }
                } else {
                    String text = driverSearchEt.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    if (carsListAdapter != null) {
                        carsListAdapter.filter(text);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

And don't forget to initialize your listview and adapter. Hope it helps as it is working for me.